# Inappropriate IOCTL for device when using capistrano in github-actions

Tags: ssh, deployment, github-actions, capistrano

I have the following yaml file set up for github-actions:

```
name: Build, Test, and Deploy to Staging

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - develop
  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  workflow_dispatch:
jobs:
  build-and-test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      DB_DATABASE: foamfactory_stage
      DB_ROOT_USER: root
      DB_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      DB_USER: admin
      DB_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.MYSQL_USER_PASSWORD }}
    steps:
      - name: Set up MySQL
        run: |
          sudo systemctl start mysql.service
          mysql -e 'CREATE DATABASE ${{ env.DB_DATABASE }};' -u${{ env.DB_ROOT_USER }} -p${{ env.DB_ROOT_PASSWORD }}
          mysql -e "CREATE USER '${{ env.DB_USER }}'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '${{ env.DB_PASSWORD }}';" -u${{env.DB_ROOT_USER}} -p${{ env.DB_ROOT_PASSWORD }}
          mysql -e "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS ${{ env.DB_DATABASE }};" -u${{env.DB_ROOT_USER}} -p${{ env.DB_ROOT_PASSWORD }}
          mysql -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ${{ env.DB_DATABASE }}.* to '${{ env.DB_USER }}'@'localhost';" -u${{env.DB_ROOT_USER}} -p${{ env.DB_ROOT_PASSWORD }}
          mysql -e "FLUSH PRIVILEGES;" -u${{env.DB_ROOT_USER}} -p${{ env.DB_ROOT_PASSWORD }}
      - name: Install SSH key to Server
        uses: shimataro/ssh-key-action@v2
        with:
          key: ${{ secrets.STAGE_API_DEPLOY_KEY }}
          name: github-actions
          known_hosts: ${{ secrets.STAGE_API_HOST_KEY }}
          config: |
            host stage.api.example.com
            IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github-actions
            IdentitiesOnly yes
            ForwardAgent yes
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Set up Ruby Environment
        uses: ruby/setup-ruby@v1
        with:
          ruby-version: 2.6.1
          bundler-cache: true
        env:
          RAILS_ENV: staging
      - name: Setup Database
        env:
          RAILS_ENV: staging
        run: bundle exec rake db:setup
      - name: Perform Database Migrations
        env:
          RAILS_ENV: staging
        run: bundle exec rake db:migrate
      - name: Run specs
        env:
          RAILS_ENV: staging
        run: bundle exec rails spec
  deploy-staging:
    needs: build-and-test
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Install SSH Host Key
        uses: shimataro/ssh-key-action@v2
        with:
          key: ${{ secrets.STAGE_API_DEPLOY_KEY }}
          name: github-actions
          known_hosts: ${{ secrets.STAGE_API_HOST_KEY }}
          config: |
            host stage.api.example.com
            IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github-actions
            IdentitiesOnly yes
            ForwardAgent yes
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Set up Ruby
        uses: ruby/setup-ruby@v1
        with:
          bundler-cache: true
      - name: Install SSH Key
        run: |
          eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
          ssh-add -D
          ssh-add ~/.ssh/github-actions
      - name: Check SSH Key Viability
        run: |
          echo "ls -al" | ssh deploy@stage.api.example.com
      - name: Deploy to staging
        run: |
          bundle exec cap staging deploy
```

The last step, 'Deploy to staging' is failing with the following output:

```
Run bundle exec cap staging deploy
  bundle exec cap staging deploy
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
  
#<Thread:0x000055e7af018820@/home/runner/work/api/api/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.2/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:10 run> terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true):
/home/runner/work/api/api/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.2/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:15:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in execute': Exception while executing as deploy@stage.api.example.com: Inappropriate ioctl for device (SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError)
    from /home/runner/work/api/api/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.2/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:11:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
/home/runner/work/api/api/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/net-ssh-6.1.0/lib/net/ssh/prompt.rb:45:in `noecho': Inappropriate ioctl for device (Errno::ENOTTY)
    from /home/runner/work/api/api/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/net-ssh-6.1.0/lib/net/ssh/prompt.rb:45:in `ask'
    from /home/runner/work/api/api/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/net-ssh-6.1.0/lib/net/ssh/authentication/methods/password.rb:68:in `ask_password'
    from /home/runner/work/api/api/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/net-ssh-6.1.0/lib/net/ssh/authentication/methods/password.rb:21:in `authenticate'
    from /home/runner/work/api/api/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/net-ssh-6.1.0/lib/net/ssh/authentication/session.rb:86:in `block in authenticate'
    from /home/runner/work/api/api/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/net-ssh-6.1.0/lib/net/ssh/authentication/session.rb:72:in `each'
    from /home/runner/work/api/api/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/net-ssh-6.1.0/lib/net/ssh/authentication/session.rb:72:in `authenticate'
    from /home/runner/work/api/api/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/net-ssh-6.1.0/lib/net/ssh.rb:255:in `start'
    from /home/runner/work/api/api/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.2/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:63:in `call'
    from /home/runner/work/api/api/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.2/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:63:in `with'
    from /home/runner/work/api/api/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.2/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:177:in `with_ssh'
    from /home/runner/work/api/api/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.2/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:130:in `execute_command'
    from /home/runner/work/api/api/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.2/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:148:in `block in create_command_and_execute'
    from /home/runner/work/api/api/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.2/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:148:in `tap'
    from /home/runner/work/api/api/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.2/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:148:in `create_command_and_execute'
    from /home/runner/work/api/api/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.2/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:61:in `test'
    from /home/runner/work/api/api/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/capistrano-passenger-0.2.1/lib/capistrano/tasks/passenger.cap:43:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
    from /home/runner/work/api/api/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.2/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:31:in `instance_exec'
    from /home/runner/work/api/api/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.2/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:31:in `run'
    from /home/runner/work/api/api/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.2/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as deploy@stage.api.example.com: Inappropriate ioctl for device


Caused by:
Errno::ENOTTY: Inappropriate ioctl for device

Tasks: TOP => rvm:hook => passenger:rvm:hook => passenger:test_which_passenger
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
deploy@stage.api.example.com's password:
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

It appears that there is some lack of communication between the ssh-agent and the capistrano task, hence the reason it appears to be asking for a password. However, on the previous step, 'Check SSH Key Viability' it's clear that the SSH key is usable and working:

```
Run echo "ls -al" | ssh deploy@stage.api.example.com
  echo "ls -al" | ssh deploy@stage.api.example.com
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
Warning: Permanently added the ECDSA host key for IP address 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX' to the list of known hosts.

<output of ls command>
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing incorrectly here, but was wondering if someone might give me a hint as to why this isn't working to deploy from github-actions.

Comment: I think I've narrowed down the issue to something to do with capistrano. When I try `cap staging deploy` locally, it now prompts me for a password. I'm not quite sure why, though, since `ssh deploy@stage.api.example.com` works without a password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this was failing was that it was using an incorrect SSH key to authenticate to Github, based on what was being used *on the server* (in this case, the server being `api.stage.example.com`). Because, on `api.stage.example.com`, my `~/.ssh/config` file showed:

```
Host github.com
 HostName github.com
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github-actions
```

It was using that file - `~/.ssh/github-actions`, and not `id_rsa` as the private key to authenticate to github. As such, I needed to add a deploy key for the appropriate repository that contained the corresponding `~/.ssh/github_actions.pub` key.

Further, I had to change the line in my `config/deploy/staging.rb` file that previously *only* used `id_rsa` to utilize either `id_rsa` or `github_actions`:

```
set :ssh_options, {
  keys: %w(~/.ssh/id_rsa ~/.ssh/github-actions),
  forward_agent: true,
}
```

Re-deploying then alleviated the errors in question.